# Issue with coalesce in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coalesce

```
Declare @Query Var-char(100)

select @Query= 'select coalesce(NULL,"test") as testing' 

Exec @Query
```

error is

```
The name 'select coalesce(NULL,"test") as testing' is not valid identifier.
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) escape the ' within the query string by typing it twice (don't use the double quotes as in your example)
2) put () after the exec command

```
Declare @Query Varchar(100)
select @Query='select coalesce(NULL,''test'') as testing'
Exec (@Query)
```